# how to run the express js(node js) in command line - linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, express, command-line

I had installed the node js, express js and npm to manage my application.
i have created the app using express js. Now I want to the run my express js app in command line in linux. currently i'm using **DEBUG=alpha-webtorrent:* npm start** to run my app.

I also want to run my app in background for forever.

Comment: You have [__`forever`__](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) module for that very purpose...

Answer (score 2):

In your command line run `npm install -g pm2` cd o your app,lication and run `pm2 start app.js` viola your server will run forever and restart if a crash occurs. Documentation for pm2 is [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Comment: it is not working for me command used forever --minUptime 100 --spinSleepTime 20 start app.js i called the app.js with app.get(/send file) not working

Answer (score 0):

install a package called forever

```
npm install forever -g
```

Go through the documentation to know more about it.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

And then use

```
forever start filename.js
```

Comment: i;m using the express js here

Comment: so ? it works on node.js and express framework as well.

Comment: it is not working for me command used **forever --minUptime 100 --spinSleepTime 20  start app.js**  i called the app.js with app.get(/send file) not working